# ProRes encoding and decoding?

Tags: video, codecs, ffmpeg, mencoder

Is there a way to encode/decode prores mov files (mostly decode)? I've been playing around with ffmpeg and mencoder/mplayer from the ubuntu repos, but they both report that it's an unknown codec. Totem as well.

I guess it comes down to getting the right codecs in place. Maybe compiling from source?

I have seen a few comments on the internet about getting mplayer/mencoder working with prores files in OS X, but I'm hoping there is a way to do this in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Times have certainly changed and now an up to date FFmpeg, including the version packaged with Xenial Xerus LTS,  will now easily encode ProRes files. The following will work well:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -c:v prores -profile:v 3 \
       -c:a pcm_s16le \
       output.mov
```

The available `-profile` settings are as follows:

```
-profile 0 = Apple ProRes Proxy
-profile 1 = Apple ProRes LT
-profile 2 = Apple ProRes 422 for SD (lower bitrate)
-profile 3 = Apple ProRes HQ for HD (higher bitrate)
```

You can test your own copy of FFmpeg for ProRes capability as follows:

```
andrew@ilium~$ ffmpeg -encoders -hide_banner | grep -i prores
 VF.... prores               Apple ProRes
 VF.... prores_aw            Apple ProRes (codec prores)
 VFS... prores_ks            Apple ProRes (iCodec Pro) (codec prores)
andrew@ilium~$
```

*(Note that as my colleague @llogan has mentioned there are actually only two ProRes encoders available: prores_aw (the default aliased to prores) and prores_ks.)*

The leading letters indicate:

```
Encoders:
 V..... = Video
 .F.... = Frame-level multithreading
 ..S... = Slice-level multithreading
```

For playback you should find that most of the major media players, examples being MPlayer, SMPlayer and VLC, will happily play these files...

**References:**

- [9.22 ProRes](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#ProRes): FFmpeg docs for the ProRes encoder. Note the extra 'private' options for the prores-ks encoder.
- [FFmpeg – Convert to Apple ProRes 422 / 4444 Simplified](https://ottverse.com/ffmpeg-convert-to-apple-prores-422-4444-hq/): A detailed look at the possibilities of the FFmpeg ProRes encoder

Comment: There are two ProRes encoders available: `prores_aw` (the default aliased to `prores`) and `prores_ks`. I never did compare them myself since I can avoid using this format. In my opinion there isn't a need for two and the best of both should be merged into one.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is unfortunately "no". There are patches floating around that enable Qt binary codec loading in MPlayer / mencoder, but they seem to be Mac-only.

ffmpeg supports [DNxHD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNxHD_codec) on Linux, which is a ProRes alternative that you may want to look into as an intermediate codec.

Comment: This is unfortunate. Hopefully progress will be made in this are. Though I would imagine it's not easy to work with proprietary codecs.